# Confusion about basic bashscript loop - until/done

Tags: bash, shell-script, whiptail

I have a bash script I'm working on to help with an installer. why doesn't this work?

```
function fn_myFunc(){
        local MYVAR=0
        until ["$MYVAR" -ne 0]; do
                whiptail --yesno "Yes or No?" --no-button "No" --yes-button "Yes" 10 70
                MYVAR=$?
                echo $MYVAR
        done
}
```

This code loops infinitely, even though if Yes is selected, the `echo $MYVAR` prints out 0 and it prints 1 if no is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should also report

```
-bash: [: missing `]'
```

or

```
-bash: [0: command not found
```

Insert whitespace where needed. In bash, `[[ ... ]]` conditions are generally easier to use than `[ ... ]`.

Comment: Where would that go? How do enable errors like that?

Comment: @USERID_UNK: I see it in the terminal, it goes to the standard error.

Comment: is there a link you could suggest for where to learn what the difference between [] and [[]] is in bash?

Comment: @USERID_UNK: `man bash` of course, maybe also [Bash Hackers](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php) or [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Comment: oh for future readers, I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash